# Why FadeTransition play at current thread completion?

Tags: java, animation, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

I want to fade-out my login window when I call REST API. I used `FadeTransition` but it starts at current thread completion. I want to fade LoginWindow first and than further code execution. Below is my code:

```
public void login() throws IOException
{
    logger.info("username = " + username.getText() + ", password = " + password.getText());

    FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(100), loginAnchorPane);
    ft.setFromValue(1.0);
    ft.setToValue(0.5);
    ft.play();



    Matcher matcher = VALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_REGEX.matcher(username.getText());
    if (!matcher.matches())
    {
        errorLabel.setText(resourceBundle.getString("invalid_email"));
        return;
    }

    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(password.getText()))
    {
        errorLabel.setText(resourceBundle.getString("invalid_password"));
        return;
    }

    errorLabel.setText("");

    System.out.println("first line " + new Date());
    boolean success = userService.login(username.getText(), password.getText());
    System.out.println("second line " + new Date());

}
```

It prints 2nd line and after that LoginWindow fade-out. i want to fade LoginWindow first and after that it should print `first line` and `second line`.

I have tried `Platform.runLater` and `new Thread()` but that also not worked.
How to play animation immediately before executing next line?

Comment: Use the `setOnFinish` method of `FadeTransition`.

Comment: @VinceEmigh : I tried that also. But `setOnFinish` does not execute until current thread is not completed.

Comment: Run your `userService::login` method in a [Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) on it's own thread. In the task [onSucceeded](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#onSucceededProperty) handler, start your fade.  In the fade [onFinish](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html#onFinishedProperty) handler, execute the code you wish to run after login has succeeded.